# Как запустить файл через нужную прогу в .bat?

Tags: bat

Можете подсказать какой должен быть код?

Это должно работать , как с пунктом в контекстном меню **"Открыть С Помощью"**.
(Виндовс)

я знаю что не по теме с пайтоном.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вы хотите куда-то (куда?) добавить в контекстное меню (чего именно?) пункт, выбор которого будет приводить к выполнению некоего батч-файла?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите запустить файл file.ext в программе по умолчанию, добавьте в .bat команду

```
start file.ext
```